# How can I better achieve my implementation of a 5x5 grid puzzle of buttons that activate the surrounding buttons on the grid using a 2D Array?

Tags: java, arrays, grid, 2d, bitset

The goal I am trying to achieve is to have a 5x5 grid of buttons. When you toggle a button, the buttons surrounding the buttons you toggle should toggle with it. Here is the grid:

```
   private static final int[][] GRID = {
        {4, 5, 6, 7, 0},
        {9, 10, 11, 12, 13},
        {14, 15, 16, 17, 18},
        {19, 20, 21, 22, 23},
        {24, 25, 26, 27, 28}
};
```

So if I press button 16, I need buttons 10, 11, 12, 17, 22, 21, 20, and 15 to toggle along with it. A major issue I've faced is that if I were to, say, toggle button 4, only buttons 5, 10, and 9 should activate with it, because there is a "wall" to the left and above button 4. I've been able to do this, but my implementation is awful:

```
   private void setButtonActivated(Player player, int button) {
        player.setButtonActivated(button);
        for (int b : getConnectedTiles(button)) {
            player.setButtonActivated(b);
        }
    }

private int[] getConnectedTiles(int button) {
    switch (button) {
        case 4:
            return new int[] { 5, 10, 9 };
        case 6:
            return new int[] { 5, 10, 11, 12, 7 };
        case 16:
            return new int[] { 10, 11, 12, 17, 22, 21, 20, 15 };
    }
    return null;
}
```

I would like to see if anyone could offer ideas for a better implementation of this.

Comment: I would like to add that it I am not limited to using an array -- I just thought that was the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make it less hardcoded:

- You need the x|y position of the button pressed
- then you can autopress the other buttons at neighbored positions: *button(x-1|y-1), button(x-1|y), ...*
- but you have to add some exceptions for buttons at positions with x=0, y=0, x=4, y=4, so you dont try to press buttons, that dont exist

If more help needed, you can ask me again. I've did simular before